# Why is rxjava2 share operator not multicasting?

Tags: rx-java, rx-java2

multicasting occurs when all my subscribers recieve the same emission before moving onto the next emission.  But when i use the share command i am not seeing multicasting. i have an expensive operation i want only done once. lets take a look at this code:

```
var  ob1 = Observable.fromArray(1,2,3,4,5).map {
       println("expensive operation")
       it * 2
   }

    fun doMultiplyBy2(){
        ob1.flatMap { Observable.just(" 1st subscriber: $it;") }.subscribe{println(it)}

        ob1.flatMap { Observable.just(" 2nd subscriber: $it;") }.subscribe{println(it)}

        ob1.share()
    }
}
```

here is the actual output:

```
    expensive operation
 1st subscriber: 2;
expensive operation
 1st subscriber: 4;
expensive operation
 1st subscriber: 6;
expensive operation
 1st subscriber: 8;
expensive operation
 1st subscriber: 10;
expensive operation
 2nd subscriber: 2;
expensive operation
 2nd subscriber: 4;
expensive operation
 2nd subscriber: 6;
expensive operation
 2nd subscriber: 8;
expensive operation
 2nd subscriber: 10;
```

but why is it repeating the expensive operation before emitting to all subscribers. its repeating the expensive operation for each subscriber? i am using share so i am expecting the output to be like this:

```
    expensive operation
 1st subscriber: 2;
 2nd subscriber: 2;
expensive operation
 1st subscriber: 4;
 2nd subscriber: 4;
expensive operation
 1st subscriber: 6;
 2nd subscriber: 6;
expensive operation
 1st subscriber: 8;
 2nd subscriber: 8;
expensive operation
 1st subscriber: 10;
 2nd subscriber: 10;
```

what else is interesting is that i found that the expected output only occurs if i do the following:

```
var  ob1 = Observable.fromArray(1,2,3,4,5).map {
       println("expensive operation")
       it * 2
   }.publish()

    fun doMultiplyBy2(){
        ob1.flatMap { Observable.just(" 1st subscriber: $it;") }.subscribe{println(it)}

        ob1.flatMap { Observable.just(" 2nd subscriber: $it;") }.subscribe{println(it)}

        ob1.connect()
    }
}
```

thus making it a connectable observable and then connecting manually.  Why does share not work ?

**UPDATE: I want to make it very clear what the issue is:**

share should be the same as publish().refCount() and i also thought that share would multicast for me but im not seeing it doing that. lets take a look at not using share but rather using publish and connect manually:

```
 var  ob1 = Observable.fromArray(1,2,3,4,5).map {
       println("expensive operation")
       it * 2
   }.publish()

    fun doMultiplyBy2(){
        //ob1 = ob1.share()
        ob1.flatMap { Observable.just(" 1st subscriber: $it;") }.subscribe{println(it)}

        ob1.flatMap { Observable.just(" 2nd subscriber: $it;") }.subscribe{println(it)}

        ob1.connect()
    }
}
```

the output of this is:

```
expensive operation
 1st subscriber: 2;
 2nd subscriber: 2;
expensive operation
 1st subscriber: 4;
 2nd subscriber: 4;
expensive operation
 1st subscriber: 6;
 2nd subscriber: 6;
expensive operation
 1st subscriber: 8;
 2nd subscriber: 8;
expensive operation
 1st subscriber: 10;
 2nd subscriber: 10;
```

which is exactly what i want. expensive operation done once per emission.

not lets change it to use share:

```
var  ob1 = Observable.fromArray(1,2,3,4,5).map {
       println("expensive operation")
       it * 2
   }.publish().refCount()//or can use share()

    fun doMultiplyBy2(){
        ob1.flatMap { Observable.just(" 1st subscriber: $it;") }.subscribe{println(it)}

        ob1.flatMap { Observable.just(" 2nd subscriber: $it;") }.subscribe{println(it)}
    }
}
```

which yields the following output:

```
    expensive operation
 1st subscriber: 2;
expensive operation
 1st subscriber: 4;
expensive operation
 1st subscriber: 6;
expensive operation
 1st subscriber: 8;
expensive operation
 1st subscriber: 10;
expensive operation
 2nd subscriber: 2;
expensive operation
 2nd subscriber: 4;
expensive operation
 2nd subscriber: 6;
expensive operation
 2nd subscriber: 8;
expensive operation
 2nd subscriber: 10;
```

what then is the purpose of publish().refCount() if its not multicasting its just like an ordinary observable. whats the point of it or share ??

Comment: `.share()` is an operator that takes an observable and returns you a new one. You're subscribing to the unshared observable twice and the creating and throwing away the shared observable.

Comment: if thats the case that share returns a new one then why does this not work for me:   var  ob1 = Observable.fromArray(1,2,3,4,5).map {
           println("expensive operation")
           it * 2
       }.share()

           fun doMultiplyBy2(){
            ob1.flatMap { Observable.just(" 1st subscriber: $it;") }.subscribe{println(it)}

            ob1.flatMap { Observable.just(" 2nd subscriber: $it;") }.subscribe{println(it)}

           // ob1.connect()
        }

Comment: Please don't put code in comments. Edit your question and add it to the end.

Comment: It'd be ideal if you could update your question, but just to let you know. The code you wrote is most likely running synchronously - so it is behaving correctly. You need an asychronous source to see the behaviour you desire.

Comment: hey thanks for your help. i updated my question. hope you can help me understand a bit more.

Comment: `Observable.fromArray(1,2,3,4,5).map { println("expensive operation") it * 2 }` is a synchronous source. It's starting, pushing out values, and completing on the same thread as subscription. So it finishes before the second subscription even starts.

Comment: Can you try `Observable.interval(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS)` as your source instead of  `Observable.fromArray(1,2,3,4,5)`?

Comment: Please read the [Getting started](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava#simple-background-computation). Calling `share`, or in fact, any operator on a reactive class and ignoring the returned object does nothing, as the classes are immutable, not a mutable builder pattern.

Comment: @ Enigmativity thanks . i see whats happening now.  your comments was correct. its multicasting after using interval.  so is it far to say that if i want to multi cast any observable i can just use the share operator ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you know `share` operator is the same `publish().refCount()`. `Refcount` makes `connectable observer` as you know. So your code is correct. But you have a missing thing that is `Thread`. I think you can understand what I want to explain about it. If not let me know!

Change the code like this

```
val ob1 = Observable.fromArray(1,2,3,4,5).map {
    println("expensive operation")
    it * 2
}.subscribeOn(Schedulers.computation()).share() 
// Add subscribeOn operator to change emitting thread from MAIN to WORK

fun doMultiplyBy2() {
    ob1.flatMap { Observable.just(" 1st subscriber: $it;") }.subscribe{println(it)}

    ob1.flatMap { Observable.just(" 2nd subscriber: $it;") }.subscribe{println(it)}
}

doMultiplyBy2()

Thread.sleep(1000) // Waiting for ending to execute
```

output

```
expensive operation
 1st subscriber: 2;
 2nd subscriber: 2;
expensive operation
 1st subscriber: 4;
 2nd subscriber: 4;
expensive operation
 1st subscriber: 6;
 2nd subscriber: 6;
expensive operation
 1st subscriber: 8;
 2nd subscriber: 8;
expensive operation
 1st subscriber: 10;
 2nd subscriber: 10;
```

Comment: So `.share()` only multicasts when an observable running on a different thread subscribes? Is there an operator that always multicasts, even when an observable from the same thread is subscribing?

Answer (score 2):

`refCount()` is equivalent to `refCount(1)`, which means that the observable will start executing when one subscriber subscribes.

So in the following example:

```kotlin
var ob1 = Observable.fromArray(1, 2, 3, 4, 5).map {
  println("expensive operation")
  it * 2
}
    .publish().refCount(1) // or .share() or .publish().refCount()

ob1.flatMap { Observable.just(" 1st subscriber: $it;") }
   .subscribe { println(it) }
ob1.flatMap { Observable.just(" 2nd subscriber: $it;") }
   .subscribe { println(it) }
```

This is what happens:

```
Observable has 0 subscribers  
Subscriber 1 subscribes  
Observable has 1 subscriber; refCount(1) condition is satisfied  
Observable EXECUTES EXPENSIVE OPERATION
Subscriber 1 executes onNext()  
Subscriber 1 executes onComplete() and unsubscribe  
Observable has 0 subscribers  
Subscriber 2 subscribes  
Observable has 1 subscriber; refCount(1) condition is satisfied  
Observable EXECUTES EXPENSIVE OPERATION
Subscriber 2 executes onNext()  
Subscriber 2 executes onComplete() and unsubscribe  
Observable has 0 subscribers
```

If you want the Observable to wait until there are 2 subscribers, you must increment to `refCount(2)`.

So in the following example:

```kotlin
var ob1 = Observable.fromArray(1, 2, 3, 4, 5).map {
  println("expensive operation")
  it * 2
}
    .publish().refCount(2) // <<<<< Increment to 2

ob1.flatMap { Observable.just(" 1st subscriber: $it;") }
   .subscribe { println(it) }
ob1.flatMap { Observable.just(" 2nd subscriber: $it;") }
   .subscribe { println(it) }
```

This is what happens:

```
Observable has 0 subscribers
Subscriber 1 subscribes
Observable has 1 subscriber
Subscriber 2 subscribes
Observable has 2 subscribers; refCount(2) condition is satisfied
Observable EXECUTES EXPENSIVE OPERATION
Subscriber 1 executes onNext()
Subscriber 2 executes onNext()
Subscriber 1 executes onComplete() and unsubscribe
Observable has 1 subscriber
Subscriber 2 executes onComplete() and unsubscribe
Observable has 0 subscribers
```

Notice how this time, expensive operation is only executed once. To generalize, if you need the expensive operation to be multicasted to N downstream observables, call `refCount(N)`